# Adder and Subtractor code not working VHDL

Tags: logic, vhdl, addition, subtraction, alu

This code works except for the add and subtract operations denoted by opcode 010 and 110 respectively. When I try to add the numbers the result looks as though a and b are being XOR'd and subtracting does A XNOR B. I have no idea why this is happening pls help. Also I am not allowed to use arithmetic plus or minus in my code the point of it is to add logically.

````
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY Lab3ALU IS
PORT(
        opcode      :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);--INPUT
        a               :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);--INPUT
        b               :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);--INPUT
        Cout            :OUT STD_LOGIC;
        Zero            :OUT STD_LOGIC;
        q               :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0));--OUTPUT
END Lab3ALU;

ARCHITECTURE description of Lab3ALU IS
        SIGNAL Reg1, Reg2, Reg3, Result : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
        SIGNAL Cin, Sum, Carry : STD_LOGIC;
BEGIN

-- Update the register output on the clock's rising edge
process (a,b, opcode)
begin
    Cin <= opcode(2);
    Reg1 <= a;--temporarirly store A in Reg1 local variable 
    Reg2 <= b;--temporarily store B in Reg2 local variable 
    Reg3 <= NOT b;
            case opcode is
                When "000" => Result <= Reg1 AND Reg2;--AND 
                When "001" => Result <= Reg1 OR Reg2;--OR

                When "010" => 
                                    addloop:    for i in 0 to 31 loop
                                                        Result(i) <= ((Reg1(i) XOR Reg2(i)) XOR Cin);
                                                        Cin <= (((Reg1(i) XOR Reg2(i))AND Cin)OR (Reg1(i) AND Reg2(i)));
                                                end loop    addloop;                                                
                When "110" => 
                                    subloop:    for i in 0 to 31 loop
                                                        Result(i) <= ((Reg1(i) XOR Reg3(i)) XOR Cin);
                                                        Cin <= (((Reg1(i) XOR Reg3(i))AND Cin)OR (Reg1(i) AND Reg3(i)));
                                                end loop subloop;
                When "100" => Result(31 downto 1) <= reg1(30 downto 0);
                                  Result(0) <= '0';
                                  Cin <= '0';
                When "101" => Result(30 downto 0) <= reg1(31 downto 1);
                                  Result(31) <= '0';
                                  Cin <= '0';
                When others => Result <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
            end case;
            if Result =  "00000000000000000000000000000000" then 
                Zero <= '1';
            else 
                Zero <= '0';
            end if;
            q<= Result;
            Cout<= Cin; 

end process;


END description;```
````

Comment: Provide the means to replicate the specific problem(s) (generally implies a testbench). A look through you code shows the architecture body signals probably want to be variables in the process statement. Signal updates don't occur while any process is executing, pending or scheduled to resume and not yet suspended. Signal updates occur in a different part of the simulation cycle while variable updates are immediate. You don't use any declaration from the last three packages made visible by use clauses.  Providing the lab assignment details would guide useful answers.

Comment: I notice that you are XORing with "cin" to get "Result". It feels that you should do this XOR only the first time(for i=0) and not for all the bits. This is what I see from a rough look at the code. There could be other errors as well. Also write a testbench and include it in the question.

Comment: Cin being a signal, it should be updated only once. Try using a variable instead, or using an array of 31 bits where each will be set only once in the loop (Cin(i))